# Hour Glass in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code an hour glass in python with the following format:

> Sample Input = 3

```
Sample Output: 

1 0 2 0 3
0 2 0 3 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 2 0 3 0
1 0 2 0 3
```

> My code:

```
#for input use:
inputString = int(input())
# For uper half
for i in range(1,inputString):
    # printing i zeroes at the 
    # beginning of each row

    for j in range(1,i):
        print("0",end=" ")
    for k in range(i,inputString+1):
        print(k,"0",end=" ")
    print()
# For lower half
for i in range(inputString , 0, -1):  

        # printing i spaces at the 
        # beginning of each row 
        for j in range(1, i): 
            print("0", end = " ") 

        # printing i to rows value 
        # at the end of each row 
        for k in range(i, inputString + 1): 
            print(k,"0",end = " ") 

        print() 

My Output:

1 0 2 0 3 0 
0 2 0 3 0 
0 0 3 0 
0 2 0 3 0 
1 0 2 0 3 0
```

I experimented with the looping parameters but I'm not able to figure it out. But unfortunately i couldn't.

Please provide some inputs.

Comment: What's the definition of a hourglass?

Comment: how are you defining an hour glass. when you give your sample input as three whats the rules that would produce the sampel output

Comment: The rules are same as of a normal hour glass the additional requirement is to add trailing and leading 0's in the required format. @ChrisDoyle

Comment: What is a "normal hourglass" then? Post the definition or a link to it in the OP.

Comment: I had referred to this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hour-glass-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take to your problem:

```
def hourglass(n, pretty_print=True):
    all_lines = []
    for ii in range(n):      
        line = np.zeros((n*2-1))            
        line[[idx for idx in np.arange(ii, n*2-1-ii, 2)]] = np.arange(ii+1, n+1, 1)
        all_lines.append(line)
    all_lines = all_lines + all_lines[-2::-1]
    if pretty_print:
        str_lines = [[str(int(val)) for val in line] for line in all_lines]
        [print(" ".join(line)) for line in str_lines]
    return np.vstack(all_lines)
```

In the case of `n=3`:

```
hourglass(3, pretty_print=True)
```

which prints:

```
1 0 2 0 3
0 2 0 3 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 2 0 3 0
1 0 2 0 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution with recursion:

```
def hourglass(n, n2=1, filler_char='0'):
    if n == n2:
        print(*'{:{filler}^{width}}'.format(filler_char.join('{}'.format(n)), width=n*2-1, filler=filler_char), sep=' ')
        return

    print(*'{:{filler}^{width}}'.format(filler_char.join(str(i) for i in range(n2, n+1)), width=n*2-1, filler=filler_char), sep=' ')
    hourglass(n, n2+1, filler_char)
    print(*'{:{filler}^{width}}'.format(filler_char.join(str(i) for i in range(n2, n+1)), width=n*2-1, filler=filler_char), sep=' ')

hourglass(7)
```

Prints:

```
1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7
0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0
0 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0
0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0
1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7
```

With `hourglass(7, filler_char=' ')` it prints:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
  2   3   4   5   6   7  
    3   4   5   6   7    
      4   5   6   7      
        5   6   7        
          6   7          
            7            
          6   7          
        5   6   7        
      4   5   6   7      
    3   4   5   6   7    
  2   3   4   5   6   7  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for k in range(i,inputString+1):
        print(k,"0",end=" ")
    print()
```

This section is your problem. Once it prints the final character (the 3 in your case), the loop tacks on another '0' and a whitespace and calls it a day. If you want whitespace instead of zeros this isn't a problem since they are visually indistinguishable, but an absence of any character obviously doesn't look the same as a '0' character. You can verify this by highlighting the sample output from the geeksforgeeks article in your browser; the leading whitespaces are there but the trailing whitespaces don't exist - after the 8 in each row is simply a whitespace then a newline character.